# Visual SVN Server on Windows 10

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 and Visual SVN Server has stopped working.

I've tried manually starting the service but that just errors.  Looking at the event log the reported error is pretty cryptic and doesn't really give me any clues as to what to attempt in order to fix it.

The error simply says:

```
The VisualSVN Server service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.
```

Looking at the Visual SVN Server specific error log shows that due to the drive having changed it's letter Visual SVN can no longer load it's UI in order for me to edit that path.

Kinda stymied ...

**UPDATE**

After poking around a bit the initial problem was that the drive hosting my repositories was assigned a new letter.  Setting that back to the original letter fixed the service and all is working again now but the MMC snapin is still erroring with:

```
Provider is not capable of the attempted operation (0x80041024)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the drive letter the service was working however I couldn't get to the bottom of the Snapin not working.

I reran the installer and executed a `Repair` and now all is working as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in [3.4.3 version](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.4.3) a while ago. Check the article [KB100: Error code 0x80041024 after upgrading to Windows 10](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00100/).

Answer (score -1):

if you still facing "Provider is not capable of the attempted operation (0x80041024)" error, you can try reinstall svn server.